# Ubuntu mute sound when laptop lid closed

Tags: bash, sound, suspend, systemd

I find it annoying when I forget to stop videos before closing my laptop and then having sound playing when opening it in public.

I tried to add the following script to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`:

```
#!/bin/bash

amixer -q -D pulse sset Master mute

echo 2 >> /home/user/test
```

The script seems to be called when suspending, as new lines are being appended to the `test` file (twice, which might indicate that the script also runs on resume - can someone confirm this assumption?).

Either the sound system re-enables itself automatically or something else is wrong. But the `amixer` command, when executed manually, works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: One event is closing lid and another one is to suspend, exactly one should be the trigger to mute? If suspend I would put `pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ true` on `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mute the sound before suspend by creating a `systemd` service.

- First, make sure that your script is executable:

  ```
  chmod u+x /path/to/your/script.sh
  ```
- Then, create a `systemd` service that runs your script, by running:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mute_before_sleep.service
  ```
- In the `nano` window enter the following:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Mute sound before suspend
  Before=suspend.target

  [Service]
  ExecStart=/path/to/your/script.sh
  User=<your_username>
  Environment=DISPLAY=:0

  [Install]
  WantedBy=suspend.target
  ```

  In `ExecStart=` enter the path to your script and in `User=` enter your username.
- Save and close `nano` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
- Finally, enable the service:

  ```
  sudo systemctl enable mute_before_sleep.service
  ```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: excution environment is different, hence amixer command returns an error

> The script seems to be called when suspending as new lines are being appended to the "test" file

Yes, it runs, but I've tested your script and the `amixer` command returns an error (reviewed with `sudo journalctl -b -u systemd-suspend.service`):

```
Jan 04 18:46:49 administrator-PC systemd-sleep[12969]: ALSA lib control.c:1373:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL pulse
Jan 04 18:46:49 administrator-PC systemd-sleep[12969]: amixer: Mixer attach pulse error: No such file or directory
```

The issue appears to be the `-D pulse` part. But simpler command `amixer -q set Master mute` works. After resume my laptop has the volume muted, error no longer appears.

> twice - which might indicate that the script also runs on resume - can someone confirm this assumption?

Yes, the script runs twice - once on suspend and once on resume; the scripts run with two positional parameters per [systemd-sleep(8)](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/systemd-sleep.8) and [Arch Wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Tools_and_scripts). The full script I've used is listed below (note, the parts which call `echo` and `date` aren't particularly relevant and were for debugging only; they may be safely removed from the script):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# this will go into journalctl log
echo SUSPEND SCRIPT STARTED
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*) amixer -q set Master mute; { echo Suspending; date >> /suspend_log.txt;}  ;;  
  post/*) { echo "Waking up from $2..."; date;} >> /suspend_log.txt ;;
  *) echo foobar;;
esac
```

As for the reason why the original amixer command works when you run it manually, likely stems from the fact that when systemd runs the script, there is no `DISPLAY` variable present in environment. By contrast when you use a GUI terminal emulator the variable is present, hence the original command works. The original command can be adapted to use the environment variable via

```
DISPLAY=:0 amixer -q -D pulse sset Master mute
```

but I'd still recommend using `amixer -q set Master mute` as environment-independent command.

Comment: I don't seem to get any errors from `amixer` on Ubuntu 18.04. Could this be specific to your system?

Comment: @user3140225 I just updated the answer to explain why it returns an error. Execution environment is missing the `DISPLAY` variable , which is present when you run `amixer` command in GUI, but will be missing from system scripts unless explicitly declared. It will also be missing if you're using system via `ssh` login or `tty` login. Try testing OP's original command again in tty1 for example.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't noticed the edit. Nice explanation and good answer. Upvoted!