# Laptop still on when lid closed

Tags: suspend, laptop

After issues with Windows, I decided to try out Linux. On Windows, when I close the lid, the fan turns off and can be placed in my backpack. Opening the lid, it quickly resumes where it left off. I am trying to recreate this functionality.

Currently, the screen shuts off, but the power light and fan is still on, leading to overheating if placed in a backpack

To fix this, I tried `sudo vim /etc/systemd/logind.conf`
uncommenting:

```
HandleSuspendKey=suspend

HandleLidSwitch=suspend

HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

and restarting.

Online, I learned that suspend is still using power, but I am unaware if turning off the display and suspend is the same thing (If the laptop is actually suspending).

To check this, I changed the power button functionality to suspend, but only a hard-reset could turn on the display after this. I know there are issues with this, but if I can't have my backpack in suspend mode in my backpack, I might be looking at different functionality.

Do you know if there is similar functionality to the Windows 'sleep on lid closed' functionality? Is setting up hibernate what I'm looking for?

My laptop is an HP envy x360 convertible 13-ar0802

Edit:
My Ubuntu version is 18.04.4
I googled power management and downloaded an app through Ubuntu Software which has a setting for when the lid is closed. It is set to suspend. Under settings - power - Suspend and power button, I only have two options, one for automatic suspend (on for both plugged and unplugged after 20 min), and when power button is pressed, power off

Edit:
I notice that the screen is at 0% brightness when it wakes from <kbd>WinKey</kbd> → *Suspend* → <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Running a video with audio in the background will resume once awoken, but no display, and I am unable to login (I think. I cant see anything, but pressing enter and my password repeatedly does nothing)

Edit:
[Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239336/ubuntu-not-detecting-lid-close-action) on `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep`

Comment: Switching the display off and suspending are not the same thing. Suspend does use power, but not enough to overheat a laptop in a backpack. It sounds like your laptop fails to suspend when closing the lid. You did not specify your version of Ubuntu, but check the system power management settings before manually editing system files.

Comment: The default system settings didn't have an option for when the lid is closed. I added my version of Ubuntu

Comment: @Christoffer Suspend when lid is closed is same as sleep when lid is closed in Windows. Suspend to disk is the same as hibernate but you need to create a `/swap` partition to achieve this. Sleep and hibernate are different. In sleep, data is stored in the RAM which uses a bit of power as it is volatile. In hibernate data is stored in the HDD or SSD which uses no power as it is non volatile.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the output of the following command in Terminal: `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep`

Comment: I still cannot get it to work :/ Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Does your laptop have dedicated Nvidia GPU? If yes then turning off the hybrid graphics will help.

Answer (score 1):

You better use the power button to put your laptop to sleep.

I've noticed that the *Suspend when laptop lid is closed* option in Tweaks doesn't seem to have the expected behavior for some laptops. So, if you close the lid, it actually just turns off the screen, instead of putting the laptop to sleep.

So, manually suspend your laptop just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I had the same issue with my laptop with Ubuntu 20. The reasons for this can vary so I can only say that diagnosing *why* it's happening helped me greatly. What I did later to solve it was just my own improvisation from various sources and my basic skills.

I found from Ubuntu forums that using the `dmesg` terminal command could give me clues as to why it isn't suspending. Using this I found that my touchpad (presuming the drivers?) was preventing suspend on looking up what the logs `dmesg` gave meant. Among the numerous entries, this caught my eye:

```
[ 1601.148777] psmouse serio3: Failed to disable mouse on rmi4-01.fn03/serio0
```

I then tried commands removing my touchpad drivers (commands mentioned below) and then closed my lid. I was so sure it was the problem because my cursor didn't work properly after opening my lid during any failed suspend.

It worked then. At this point, I could manually run those add/remove commands in the terminal manually each time whenever I chose to suspend.

I then improvised and made a `systemd` service on lid close/open ([here's one answer which helped](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199959/ubuntu-mute-sound-when-laptop-lid-closed)) which ran bash scripts that removed my touchpad drivers and put them back, respectively. The scripts just had the commands to remove/put them back.

The commands for removing/adding the touchpad are:

```
rmmod psmouse //remove

modprobe psmouse //put back
```

They need `sudo` if running as a user, `systemd` runs it as root by default if you remove the username parameter.

Worked then!

So this is how I did it and can only emphasise the importance of my first point of diagnosing why. The problems causing it despite everything seemingly fine must be case-by-case/device-to-device.

Comment: Nice answer, but could you [edit] and provide examples of the touchpad messages in `dmesg`, and the commands that you used to remove, or at least the link to the other answer. Also could you provide details of the `systemd` service and/or the link? These extra details might help someone else, who isn't so proficient in Ubuntu, solve their issue.

Comment: @Greenonline Thanks for your help, I'll get to doing that soon.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Gnome Tweaks if you haven't already.
2. Make sure suspend when the lid is closed is turned on.
   [image: Suspend in tweaks]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107982/discussion-on-answer-by-sasuke-uchiha-laptop-still-on-overheats-when-lid-closed).